# Сокрытие столбцов таблицы и чекбокс

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Делаю сокрытие столбцов таблицы по чекбоксам. JS код взял [отсюда](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html).

Проблема в следующем. Столбцы скрываются, но чекбоксы не помечаются выбранными. 
Если убрать из кода `e.preventDefault();`, то тогда с чекбоксами все в порядке, но столбцы не скрываются. При клике по чекбоксу не добавляются никакие классы, поэтому я не понимаю, что делать.

Как это решить?

```js
    var table = $('#accounts').dataTable();

    $('label.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // Get the column API object
        var column = table.api().column($(this).attr('data-column'));
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible(!column.visible());
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox toggle-vis" data-column="0">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Id</span>
</label>

<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox toggle-vis" data-column="1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
    <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
    <span class="custom-control-description">Name</span>
</label>

<table id="accounts" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td><td>Jack</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td><td>Peter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: а попробуйте превентдефолт убить и ивент смениь на `change`. ПС: мне бы не пришло в голову юзать тут событие клик...

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, У меня опыта во всем стеке веб-технологий пару дней. Было бы здорово если бы вы привели минимальный пример кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('label.toggle-vis input').on('click', function (e) {
   // Get the column API object
   var column = table.api().column($(this).closest("label").data('column'));
   // Toggle the visibility
   column.visible(!column.visible());
});
```

Comment: Благодарю. Можете объяснить почему при клике по чекбоксу не добавляются классы/аттрибуты?

Comment: @maxwell так нет же никакого кода, добавляющего классы/атрибуты. Изменяется только свойство DOM-элемента `checked`. Или я Вас не понял?

Comment: Правильно, просто я думал, что должно все работать также как и со стандартным чекбоксом: если есть атрибут checked, то отмечен, если нет, то нет.

Comment: @maxwell Так и есть. Поэтому я бы изменил последнюю строчку на `column.visible(this.checked);`